# Adding a new facility to syslog

Tags: syslog

The docs give a fixed list of facilties for syslog, but it's clearly possible to have more (http isn't on the list). Do I just describe it in the conf file and start using it or is is more involved?  (It's an ecommerce system and I want to log the payment activities better.)

Answer (score 4):

The syslog protocol only allows the predefined facilities defined in [RFC 3164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164). Most (if not all) syslog daemons will process messages with different facility identifiers as corrupt.

But you can easily use the facilities `local0` through `local7` for your custom logging needs, which is what they are there for.

Comment: How does Apache do it?

Comment: It doesn't. Apache httpd either writes its own log files (not using the system's syslogd) or uses the configured facility (see documentation on ErrorLog: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot. You probably want to take a look at the `filter` function of [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html) or [syslog-ng](http://www.softpanorama.org/Logs/Syslog_ng/filter_functions_with_examples.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter function in the aforementioned tools. You can also use a syslog manager such as LogZilla to filter search and graph results based on facility.